# How can I create the Cloud Web Service to Push Notification on Windows Phone?

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

While working with [Windows Phone Push Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), I got myself stuck in the part of creating the "cloud web service" to receive the negotiated URL and retrieve updates to the mobile device. Is it possible to create this Web Service **without** using Windows Azure services (I don't want to pay anything, I just want to push with my services to my apps)? And how can I create this Cloud Web Service and find some working samples/examples?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use Windows Azure services. Any web-server will work. Does your application have a server side? If it does, use that server to send push notifications and to receive the notification channel URI from the app.

The server can be written in any language you prefer : JAVA, PHP, C#, etc...
The code would depend on the programming language you use to write your server.

Examples :

- If you prefer Java, you can use [java-mpns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-mpns).
- If you prefer C#, you can use [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp).
- If you prefer PHP, here's a [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898789/send-push-notification-for-windows-phone-7-using-php).

Comment: Thank you, Eran! I'll try your sollution.